# How Base class members gets copied in inheritance when we copy/assign derived class objects?

Tags: c++, inheritance, copy-constructor, deep-copy, assignment-operator

I have following scenario:

I have an Abstract base class with 
no copy constructor 
no assignment operator
has some data members

a derived class (derived from above base class)
has assignment operator
has some data members

How the members of base class will be copied when we copy a derived class object to another existing derived class object. 
I understand as we have an assignment operator defined for derived class which copies derived class members but how base class members will be copied, will it be through default assignment operator?

Comment: Please show code instead of describing it.

Answer (score 3):

> How the members of base class will be copied

Since there's no explicit copy constructor, one will be generated by the compiler.  It will in turn call/generate copy constructors for the data members of the base class.  At the end, builtin types (`int`, `float`, pointers! *etc* are simply copied), types with copy constructors can copy themselves, any other type will generate a compile time error.